# FM antenna isolation

Tags: antenna, frequency-modulation

I want to connect a car antenna (FM radio) to a phone's jack sleeve to provide a good antenna signal to the phone (for its FM radio part).

As the car might add some supply DC to the antenna, I decided to isolate it with a 100nF series ceramic capacitor.

However it doesn't really meet my expectations: reception is better than without any cables in the jack socket, but I would like to see a similar reception, as with the original radio (if I plug the same antenna without the cap into it).

Did I make a mistake with the 100nF cap?

To be more exact: **can I (is 100nF a good value) isolate DC current from an FM antenna wire which shall function as antenna in the 88.0-108.0MHz band with a series 100nF ceramic capacitor?**

Comment: Unless it is open the issue is with your expectation of the phone, not the cap.  Questions on the usage of products are not on topic here.

Comment: does the FM radio operate on similar frequecies as the phone?

Comment: I wanted to focus my question more on the impact of a 100nF series capacitor on an FM antenna wire, specifically in the common FM frequency band between 88 and 108 MHz. Could you please tell me which SE site shall fit better for this? Thank you!

Comment: I want to provide FM antenna to the phone to use it as FM radio! Will edit the question

Comment: Try a 4n7 instead and report back

Comment: A 100 nF capacitor will have *no* impact on a broadcast FM antenna, which is why your problem (whatever it is) has nothing to do with the capacitor, and everything to do with the *usage of an undocumented product*.